# Laravel - Eloquent - Get a ralationship without foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm working on a Laravel project, where i have the models "Reservation" and "Week".

The model "Week" has a starting date and a price, the model "Reservation" has a starting date and an ending date.

I want to be able to do a eloquent selection like this: `Reservation::with('weeks')->get()`, but if i do something below eloquent doesn't recognize it as a relationship, and i can't use "HasMany" in Reservation model because i don't associate the tables with ids, but only with dates.

How can i get the weeks as a relationship?

```
class Reservation extends Model
{
    public function weeks()
            {
                return Week::whereDate('starting_date', '>=', $this->starting_date)
                    ->whereDate('starting_date', '<', $this->ending_date)
                    ->orderBy('starting_date')
                    ->get();
            }
}
```

edited: thanks @Tim Lewis

Comment: `Reservation::all()->with('weeks')` is no good; `::all()` converts to a Collection, which doesn't have a `with()` method. Try `Reservation::with('weeks')->get()` instead. But, if you can't define a relationship, that also won't work. You can't eager load `weeks` (`with('weeks')`) since it doesn't return a Relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed it thanks this repository: https://github.com/johnnyfreeman/laravel-custom-relation

The repository is archived and not installable for Laravel 8, so i just copied the files in this folders:

- app\Relations\Custom.php
- app\Traits\HasCustomRelations.php

This allows me to use `Reservation::with('weeks')->get();` with eadger constraints

```
use App\Models\Week;
use App\Traits\HasCustomRelations;

class Reservation extends Model
{
    use HasCustomRelations;

    public function weeks()
    {
        return $this->custom(
            Week::class,

            // add constraints
            function ($relation) {
                if($this->starting_date && $this->ending_date) {
                    $relation->getQuery()
                        ->where('weeks.starting_date', '>=', $this->starting_date)
                        ->where('weeks.starting_date', '<',  $this->ending_date);
                }
                else {
                    $relation->getQuery();
                }
            },

            // add eager constraints
            function ($relation, $models) {
                $starting_date = $models[0]->starting_date;
                $ending_date = $models[count($models)-1]->ending_date;
                $relation->getQuery()
                    ->where('weeks.starting_date', '>=', $starting_date)
                    ->where('weeks.starting_date', '<', $ending_date);
            },

            // add eager matcher
            function ($models, $results, $foreignTable, $relation) {
                foreach ($models as $model) {
                    $model->setRelation($foreignTable, $results
                        ->where('starting_date', '>=', $model->starting_date)
                        ->where('starting_date', '<',  $model->ending_date));
                }
                return $models;
            }
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Just use an accessor to get the weeks:

```
public function getWeeksAttribute()
{
    return Week::whereDate('starting_date', '>=', $this->starting_date)
        ->whereDate('starting_date', '<', $this->ending_date)
        ->orderBy('starting_date')
        ->get();
}
```

and you'll be able to get the weeks as if it were any other attribute. If you need to serialize your model to Json, remember to add `weeks` to the [`$appends` array](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) in your model.

Comment: Thanks, this work if i do something like this:
Reservation::first()->weeks
But if i do something like this:

Reservation::with('weeks')->first()

I get this error:
Call to undefined relationship [weeks] on model [App\Models\Reservation].

Comment: You don't use "with" because this is an accesor, not a relationship. Since you don't have a foreign key in any of your two tables, a real relationship is just not possible. I believe this is the next best solution.

Comment: An accesor works also without specify $appends in models, but using Reservation::first()->append('weeks'), but what i want is to do ->with('weeks') for a query optimization. With an accesor if i select more reservations, the append method execute a query for every model. The best solution for me could be an "HasMany" relationship without foreign_key, but i don't know how to do it